# Split file in dynamic name in unix

Tags: file, unix, split

I have a file of 500 million records and I have to split this file into files of 1 million each. File should be named dynamically with numeric suffix. I tried :

```
split -dl 1000000 myInputFile.txt  output_
```

But after creating 99 files( like output_00... output_99) , I got the error:

```
split: output file suffixes exhausted
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man split says

```
-a 3
```

to use 3 digits suffixes

If all else fails read the manual